# Отправка уведомлений через Firebase когда приложение активно

Tags: ionic, fcm

Пишу приложение с использованием `ionic`. Отправляю пуши через сервер на `PHP`.
Все работает ка надо:

Когда приложение активно - попадаю в

```
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
   /////
});
```

Когда приложение свернуто - появляется уведомление верху телефона.

Подскажите, есть ли возможность отправлять пуши так, что бы уведомление вверху появлялось всегда и в `subscribe` я попадал только когда пользователь открыл `push` вручную?
Спасибо!!!